# Responsive image and grid

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes.One containing an image and the other with text.
How can I make the image fit according to the size of the box?Cause at the moment the image is flowing over the box size as you can see in my code:

```
     <div class="left-column">
        <img src="http://www.opulencesoaps.co.za/Images/2links.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="right-column">
        <h2>Nevex has the experience</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad cum rem a tempore tenetur unde alias amet deserunt veritatis. Nemo, iste, quis! Eligendi dolores similique id nostrum non, in velit?</p>
        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="There will be more information in future">FIND OUT MORE</button>
    </div>
```

Below is the css

```
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }  
   img{
    max-width=100%;
    height: auto;
   width: auto;
   }   
 .left-column{
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  float: left;
  border:1px solid red;
 }
 .right-column{
  width:50%;
 float: left;
 border:1px solid red;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/b2htLvcj/4/

At the end I would like to have both boxes next to each other with the same size and the text aligned to the center using media queries.

A help will be appreciated.

Comment: first of all, use `:`, not `=` for `max-width: 100%`

Comment: as mention in previous comment : https://jsfiddle.net/b2htLvcj/6/

Comment: In a way it works for the image...but the image does not align with the box next to it.If you add Claudio's code will be perfect.
Thanks for the correction on the typo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for the size of your column.
But you need to add a contain div.

Example :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.header{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.left-column{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.right-column{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;

  margin: 0;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.content{
      display:flex;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="left-column">
            <img src="http://www.opulencesoaps.co.za/Images/2links.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-column">
            <h2>Nevex has the experience</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad cum rem a tempore tenetur unde alias amet deserunt veritatis. Nemo, iste, quis! Eligendi dolores similique id nostrum non, in velit?</p>
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="There will be more information in future">FIND OUT MORE</button>
        </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Out of all attempts it worked perfectly and I can see the entire image.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Place the image inside a div with a class `image`. Check this out.

HTML

```
  <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.opulencesoaps.co.za/Images/2links.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.image img {
    max-width:100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your CSS code: `max-width=100%;`  should be  `max-width:100%;` with two points.